# Call to a member function X on a non-object in Y on line Z

Tags: php

```
<?php
class Conversor {
    function toLowerFirst($word) {
        $word = 'test';
        return $word;
    }
}

class Test {
    function test() {
        $word = 'Test';
        $word = $this->conversor->toLowerFirst($word);
        echo $word;
    }
}

class Launcher {
    function launch() {
        $Test = new Test();
        $Test->conversor = new Conversor();
        $Test->test();
    }
}

$launcher = new Launcher();
$launcher->launch();
?>
```

Why doesn't it echo 'test'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your function `test()` is the same as the class name - it looks like an old-style constructor, so it's being run when you do `new Test()`, i.e. before you set `conversor`.

Rename the function or add a new-style constructor to Test: `__construct()`

Comment: I thought starting with a t in the function and T in the class were going to differentiate them.

Answer (score 1):

Because the call `$word = $this->conversor->toLowerFirst($word);` returns an error, the function `toLowerFirst` doesn't exist at that time (you call the function through a non-existant instance of Conversor)

Replace `$word = $this->conversor->toLowerFirst($word);` with `$word = Conversor::toLowerFirst($word);` and it will work.

Edit: the __construct is a better solution, because my suggestion results in 2 times the echo.. (test is treated as a constructor for Test)

Comment: @Delirium tremens, this is the reason! Nice answer MisticEarth. That said maybe you should re-think the flow of the program as this will probably throw a Strict Standards warning.

Comment: In the unsimplified code, the part that corresponds to $word = $this->conversor->toLowerFirst($word); runs before the part that corresponds to $Test->conversor = new Conversor(); runs.